# React conditional router for Cordova

Tags: reactjs, cordova, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to switch between hash history and browser history for a React app in Cordova.

On the web I want to use Browser history, in Cordova I have to use HashHistory

I've tried something like

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import createHashHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'


export default window.cordova ? createHashHistory() : createBrowserHistory()
```

But nothing loads.

```
createHashHistory() works fine.
```

Is there anyway to make this conditional?

i.e. so in cordova it uses hash history and if not it will use the browser history?

The issue is highlighted [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2161) with this hack

```
   let baseName = document.location.pathname.split('index.html')[0] + 'index.html';
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this conditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import createHashHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
import App from './App'

var history
const startApp = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={history} >
            <Route component={App} />
        </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
}

if(!window.cordova) {
    history = createBrowserHistory()
    startApp()
}
else{
    history = createHashHistory()
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', startApp, false)
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please explain the code you wrote and make sure to follow these Guidelines: [answer]